# TTStyledText that recognizes URLs without http:// scheme

Tags: iphone, three20

I am using TTStyledText to display text with potential markup on a TTStyledTextLabel.

If text contains something like "http://stackoverflow.com" TTStyledText autogenerates the markup and linkifies said text.

The problem is I also want "www.stackoverflow.com" to appear as valid hyperlinks, as well as anything that reasonably resembles an http URL, even if the scheme is missing.

Any way to do that with TTStyleText or do I need to recognize the URL and reformat the text myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found `TTStyledText` to be woefully underpowered and missing a lot of functionality.  This is a good example.  I think in order to make this work you'll need to as you say pre-format the text portion before you pass it in.